# Pdf not generated using iText PDF when image not found

Tags: java, itext

Code is working well when image is found on said path.

Code:

```
    ...
    Document document=new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("D:/pdfSample.pdf"));
    document.open();
    String text="<html><body>hello<img src='http://pathOfImage/Image.gif' alt='' /></body></html>";
    HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
    htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(text));
    document.close();
    System.out.println( "PDF Created!" );
```

But if image is not found, pdf is not getting generated i.e. image **alt** property is not working. What can be done?

Comment: what is the error you getting???

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://imagepath/image.gif

Comment: Please, stop using deprecated versions of iText(Sharp) and start using new versions. XMLWorker completely replaced HTMLWorker.

Comment: @MichaëlDemey demey: I am using it in Java

Comment: HTMLWorker is also deprecated in Java. Please use XMLWorker.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot @MichaelDemey. XMLWorker works like a charm! Thanks a lot.